# R: Import different packages that export a class with the same name - namespace is getting ignored

Tags: r

I have encountered some rather strange behavior from R. I tested it on Windows and Ubuntu with the same results.

So let's assume I have a package called `QS1API` with the following substructure:

```
.
├── DESCRIPTION
├── man
├── NAMESPACE
├── QS1API.Rproj
├── R
│   ├── class-API.R
│   └── QS1API.R
```

The `class-API.R` includes the definition of a class called `API`:

```
.API <-  methods::setRefClass(
  Class = ".API"
)

#' @export
API <- function(...) {
  tmpObj <- methods::new(".API", ...)
  return(tmpObj)
}

.API$methods(
  print_name = function() {
    cat("Hey it is QS1")
  }
)
```

Now I have a package called `QS2API` with the following substructure:

```
.
├── DESCRIPTION
├── man
├── NAMESPACE
├── QS2API.Rproj
├── R
│   ├── class-API.R
│   └── QS2API.R
```

This package also exports a **class with the name**, i.e. `API`, however, its `print_name` **function is different**:

```
.API <-  methods::setRefClass(
  Class = ".API"
)

#' @export
API <- function(...) {
  tmpObj <- methods::new(".API", ...)
  return(tmpObj)
}

.API$methods(
  print_name = function() {
    cat("Hey it is QS2")
  }
)
```

Here comes the strange part! If I access the `print_name` function in different sessions, all good:

```
QS1API::API()$print_name
Class method definition for method print_name()
function () 
{
    cat("Hey it is QS1")
}
<environment: 0x55c369046158>
```

New Session:

```
QS2API::API()$print_name
Class method definition for method print_name()
function () 
{
    cat("Hey it is QS2")
}
<environment: 0x559ab67de3e8>
```

**But when I use the same session, the namespace of the class seems to be totally ignored:**

```
QS1API::API()$print_name
Class method definition for method print_name()
function () 
{
    cat("Hey it is QS1")
}
<environment: 0x558badba26c0>

QS2API::API()$print_name
Class method definition for method print_name()
function () 
{
    cat("Hey it is QS1")
}
<environment: 0x558bae0858a8>
```

Actually, isn't that exactly why the namespace should be written in front of functions/classes? What is going on here?

Comment: Are you using devtools to test load these package? Or are you building them and installing them with install.packages?

Comment: building them with shortcut ctrl+B

Comment: What happens if you reverse the load order?  Does a call to QS1 come back with "hey it is Qs2"?

Comment: yes exactly. Can you reproduce the issue? This is kinda strange..

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue.  I built similar packages,  using R CMD BUILD  (under MacOS).   I installed them both and each returned the expected message.

Comment: I dond't know what I'm doing wrong here...

Comment: @CarlWitthoft did you also try to install the packages with devtools::install() or simply by building them via Rstudio GUI?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Did change anything from the above code or did you just copy paste it? I get the same result when using R CMD BUILD and R CMD INSTALL

Comment: I copied and pasted,  on MacOS 11.7.4 .  I used `package.skeleton()` to create the framework, built with a Terminal session "R CMD BUILD"  then used  R.app gui  menu item "Install from local source" to install the packages.

Comment: that is super strange. Can you test this on windows or Linux? Which R version are you using?